# Is there a reputation bug at the moment?

Tags: bug, reputation

I answered a question a short time ago and I only earned the reputation from the upvotes, not from the user accepting my answer.

My [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754119/alon-eitan?tab=reputation) is 9,131, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) it shows 9,146 (See attched screenshot):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sometimes happens when a user manages to submit both votes on the exact same second. The system automatically recalculates your reputation after certain other events occur (like deletions), which not only corrects your reputation due to those events, but also compensates for various other situations - like race conditions where the database was updating your reputation twice from the same value, and one overrides the other. It should fix itself within about 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept when the system let me. It was just updated to the correct count. I was too hasty